# Uncaught ReferenceError: timeTicket is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here in script i gave design for gauge meter but it is not displaying.It should be want to display gauge and fix these problems.i am new to js so i can't find the error.

** option = {

```
       series: [
           {
               splitNumber: 10,
               axisLine: {
                   lineStyle: {
                       color: [[0.5, 'red'], [0.8, 'orange'], [1, 'green']],
                       width: 20
                   }
               },
               axisTick: {
                   splitNumber: 10,
                   length: 25,
                   lineStyle: {
                       color: 'auto'
                   }
               },
               axisLabel: {
                   textStyle: {
                       color: 'auto'
                   }
               },

               pointer: {
                   width: 5
               },
               title: {
                   show: true,
                   offsetCenter: [0, '-35%'],
                   textStyle: {
                       fontWeight: 'bolder',
                       fontSize: 40
                   }
               },

               data: [{ value: 50, name: 'OEE' }]
           }
       ]
   };

   clearInterval(timeTicket);
   timeTicket = setInterval(function () {
       document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID %>").innerHTML;

   }, 2000)
   var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: "line", data: data, });
```

Comment: Where is the script you are asking the question about?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: cant able to upload code i am trying pls wait

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: uploaded the code

Comment: and chart is <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="200"></canvas>

Comment: clearInterval(timeTicket);  maybe you should delete this  line

Comment: Thanks iptton but the gauge is not showing

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn to identify what kind of error message is for different situation. In your case, it mention **timeTicket is not defined** which means that it **does not recognize** what your *timeTicket* is. Sometime this could happen because of the scoping problem. Simply swap the `clearInterval(timeTicket)` to the line after you *declared* the *timeTicket*.

```
timeTicket = setInterval(function () {
   document.getElementById("<%=lbl.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
}, 2000)
clearInterval(timeTicket);
```

Comment: Thanks the error is gone but the gauge is not showing

Comment: You have to test out the necessary parts of the code which will affect the gauge such as *make sure your clearInterval() function can works by testing other values* or *check where is your myChart object is called*

Comment: using `console.log()` or `typeof` to test out whether the objects, variables, and functions are working only further consider the sequencing problems

Comment: I called it in canvas <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="200"></canvas>

Comment: errrr do you notice that you declared **myNewChart** but you assign **myChart** as your id?

Comment: and I'm not that familiar with ASP so I'm not sure that whether embed the _object_ in *id* attribute will work